# Associations in Visual Studio 2008 class diagrams

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I generate class diagram in Visual Studio 2008 using View Class Diagram I always get a bunch of class boxes without methods. The only lines in the diagram are inheritance.

Is it possible, and if so how do I get associations (aggregation and composition might not be possible, but at least an association line indicating they are some how connection. Preferably with an arrow) visualized?

And is it possible to change it so that methods are shown after generating a diagram by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a property as an association just right click on a property in the diagram editor (not the Class Details panel) and choose either "Show as Association" or "Show as Collection Association".  Obviously you will need to make the property visible in the diagram editor first.  Typically I only show public properties.

And I don't believe there is a way to always show associations.

Comment: If I select all the classes (Ctrl+A) and Expand them all and then I choose Layout Diagram the class diagram a lot of my expanded classes are collapsed again. There are close to 100 classes and 10 properties in each. Is there a more smooth way to do this than to manually do it?